# How to prevent bubbles from touching the svg frame/border when using D3.js force?

Tags: svg, d3.js, bubble-chart

I am using D3.js library to develop a bubble chart. I got some sample from the internet which using force simulation to show the bubble nodes. I liked it very much and thought to include it in my project, but there's an issue where sometimes the bubbles get cut by the surrounding SVG frame/border. I tried understanding and debugging the code, and I concluded that the final position of the bubbles is decided by the force simulation.
I thought of the below 2 solutions:

1. Restricting the bubbles within the specified region (actual SVG frame size can be bigger)
2. Pre-define the size of the frame (width/height) based on the region the bubbles occupy due to D3 force simulation. In other words, determine the region that would be calculated by the force simulation and then define the SVG width/height

Is there a way where we could implement one of the 2 solutions that I mentioned? Is there any other solution to prevent the force simulated bubbles not touch the SVG frame/border?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [d3 v4 force layout with boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409983/d3-v4-force-layout-with-boundary)

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd approach is not feasible because the force simulation is too non-linear and unpredictable to pre-determinate its area of action. Also, depending on the forces at play, the nodes can repel themselves indefinitely, so expanding the SVG during the simulation can create an ever-expanding SVG element.

The 1st approach is the way to go. To restrict the bubbles, you can edit the function that updates the position (usually called *ticked()* in examples) and **manually add a boundary using *Math.min()* and *Math.max()*:**

*The following code is a fragment from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492):*

```js
function tick() {
    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, 
          d.x)); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, 
          d.y)); });
  }
```

Things to note:

1. Remember to account for the radius of the bubble so that it can be tangent with the boundary.
2. Note that the code not only returns the limited value, but also assigns it to d.x and d.y. This is necessary because the simulation uses the current value of the d.x and d.y to compute the next frame of the simulation.